# How to bind counter value to the textblock?

Tags: wpf, binding

I'd like to be able to see the counter value in the textblock which incremented on a click of the button. I need to bind it to the textblock. I am wondering what will be the correct way to do it.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=counter}" />
<Button x:Name="Nextbt" Content="Next" Click="ClickNextButton"/>
```

C#:

```
private void ClickNextButton(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e){
counter += 1;
if (counter == 1)
{

}
if (counter == 2)
{

}}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the current approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make a public property, that returns the counter value. Name it "Counter"
2) Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and call PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Counter")) for every change of the counter-value
3) Change your markup as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=counter,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

This is only one possiblity of many. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) link leads you to an overview of DataBinding. I could imagine that this document will clarify the above steps.

**Update**

As you wished in your comment, here an example, I assume you are in the main-window. I have changed some things against the above sequence: I have set the DataContext in the constructor. Therefore it is no more necessary to use a relative source for the Binding. Both ways are possible (and both are not very elegant, but to learn WPF-Databinding, they are appropriate). Maybe you try both, the only difference is the binding-declaration and the constructor code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged{    

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        int m_counter;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext=this;
        }


        public int Counter {
            get { return m_counter; }
            set {
                if (m_counter != value) {
                    m_counter = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Counter"));
                }
            }
        }
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {    
            if (null != PropertyChanged) {        
                PropertyChanged(this,e);    
            }
        }

        private void ClickNextButton(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e){
             Counter += 1; 
             if (Counter == 1) { } 
             if (Counter == 2) { } 
        } 

        Continue with class declaration...
```

And the XAML:

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Counter}" /> 
        <Button x:Name="Nextbt" Content="Next" Click="ClickNextButton"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the lead. I am wondering if you can post any working sample. I was not able to make it work yet. Thank you again.

Comment: It is working great! Thank you for your help. I highly appreaciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` needs to be exposed as a public property in order for your TextBlock to bind to it. Preferably, the property should implement change notification. See [MSDN's Data Binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) for starters!

Comment: I made it public but it did not change the result. It looks like I need to inplement correctly the way that HCL decribed. I was hoping it can be simplier.